# $.post() error Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery

This code:

```
$(function(){
     $.get("test.html", function(data){
      $(".msgs").text(data)
     })
})
```

Gives me this console error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/wamp/www/JQuery%20lab/check.php?username=&password=.
Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

You are viewing your HTML file directly from the webserver serving directory, not from `http://localhost/`, so the browser is blocking the `GET` request.

Web browsers block certain kinds of JavaScript requests due to security policies, and sending a request from a local file seems to be one of them.

Comment: You are right very thanks , i tried it from http://localhost/  , so it has been applied

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is adding this to your php script:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```